# How do I set the filename for OpenGL shader compile errors returned by glGetShaderInfoLog?

Tags: opengl, glsl

When compiling shaders with OpenGL, you can retrieve log lines by calling `glGetShaderInfoLog`. At least in the driver I'm using (Nvidia), this will return results like:

```
0(14) : error C1035: assignment of incompatible types
```

The leading `0` is the index of the string passed to `glShaderSource` and the number in parentheses is the line number.

Can I set that value to the actual filename so the compiler errors are more useful? Alternatively, is there a consistent way to parse the driver output?

Comment: You know which shader object you are getting the information log from. Therefore you can log some additional information before the shader information log. OpenGL doesn't know anything about the file system.

Comment: Obviously OpenGL can't know anything about the file system _if you don't tell it_. The question is, can you give it more context to make the output more useful? This is a pretty normal concept in any other compilation environment or programming language.

Comment: The shader information log is generated by the graphics driver. Actually, you want to configure the error format of the nvidia graphics driver. I don't think this is possible. Don't waste time and generate additional output yourself.

Comment: Might see if your GL implementation emits names set by [`glObjectLabel()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output#Object_names) in the info log.  You're kinda SOL if your shader objects are composed from multiple files/strings though, not seeing anything that lets you name particular strings within a shader object.

Comment: @genpfault I didn't know about glObjectLabel so thanks for that! Your suspicion was correct though--it doesn't work in this case unfortunately.